# predict values from GAM for grouped dataframe in R

Tags: r, apply, purrr, gam

I have a dataset of mean annual temperature values at different latitudes in different years. I want to use this to predict the latitude at which a given temperature could be found in a given year; i.e., "in 1980, at what latitude would the mean annual temperature have been 20C?"

I need to use year-specific models for this, because the relationship between latitude and temperature has changed over time (although not in the sample data below, which is randomly generated). This will involve:

1. Fit GAMs to a dataset grouped/split by year.
2. For each different GAM (that is, for each year), use `predict.gam` to calculate a predicted value for every element in a list of temperatures.
3. Recombine these to get a dataframe with columns representing `year`, `newdata_value`
   (the temperature value used for prediction), and `predicted_value` (latitude from feeding each `newdata_value` into the year-specific GAM).

Here's a toy dataset:

```
years <- seq(1968, 2018, 1)
lat <- seq(34.5, 44.5, 1)
dat <- expand.grid(years, lat)
names(dat) <- c("years","lat")
dat$temp <- runif(dim(dat)[1], 5, 20) # add random temperature data points 
newdata_values <- seq(2, 16, 2) # temperature values to use for prediction
```

I've tried various `purrr` and `split-apply-combine` solutions and haven't figured anything out. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another option is to fit a model that allows the lat/temp relationship to vary by year.  There are several options for this.  The following fits a model where each year has an independent relationship:

```
gam(lat ~ year + s(temp, by = year), data = dat)
```

Note that for this formulation `year` should be encoded as a factor.

An alternative would be to allow the lat/temp relationship to vary *smoothly* by year, a reasonable model if this relationship gradually changes over time.  In this case you will want to use a *tensor product smooth* (`te()`) to indicate a two-way interaction between variables that are on different scales (degrees, years):

```
gam(lat ~ te(temp, year), data = dat)
```

In both cases you can then make a prediction with `predict.gam(model, newdata = new_dat)`, where `new_dat` has both `year` and `temp` columns.

Answer (score 2):

One approach would be to use nested dataframes. I used code found in [this tutorial](https://community.rstudio.com/t/adding-nested-observations-to-a-dataframe/4949/2).

You can group by year and use `nest`. I'll also rename columns and add the new values to predict:

```
library(tidyverse); library(mgcv)
names(dat) <- c('year', 'lat', 'temp')
dat2 <- dat %>% group_by(year) %>% nest()

dat2 <- dat2 %>% mutate(newdata_value = rep(list(newdata_values), n_distinct(year)))
```

You then define some helper functions to made the tidyverse code cleaner (I'm assuming your using gam from the `mgcv` package). Then map the model function to the data and map the predict function to the fitted models:

```
lat_gam <- function(df) {
  gam(lat ~ s(temp), data = df)
}

pred_gam <- function(mod) {
  predict.gam(mod, newdata = data.frame(temp = newdata_values))
}

dat2 <- dat2 %>% mutate(model = map(data, lat_gam))

dat2 <- dat2 %>% mutate(predicted_value = map(model, pred_gam))


dat2 %>% select(-data, -model) %>% unnest(cols = c(newdata_value, predicted_value))
```

The last line is totally optional, just gets the final output to print like the way you specified in 3)

Comment: This is really neat. Is it possible to add multiple arguments to the functions so that the column names of `dat` don't have to be the same every time, and can just be specified in `lat_gam` and `pred_gam`? I tried adding them to the functions and then to the `mutate(newcol = map())` calls, but I don't think `map` works with multiple inputs.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [data.table](/questions/tagged/data.table) approach:

```
library(data.table)
library(mgcv)

setDT(dat)

dat[, .(pred = c(predict.gam(gam(lat ~ temp), list(temp = newdata_values))),
        newdata_values),
    by = years]
```

The only problem I had was that the `predict.gam(...)` call returns an array. The `c(predict.gam(...))` converts it to an array.

A similar base approach that does not have perfect formatting:

```
by(dat[, -1],
   dat[, 1],
   function(DF) {
     mod = gam(lat ~ temp, data = DF)
     pred = predict.gam(mod, list(temp = newdata_values))

     data.frame(newdata_values, pred)
     }
   )
```

Comment: I really like the `data.table` approach but when I run that script I get a dataframe that I think just has the original data: 
`> head(dat)
   years  lat      temp
1:  1968 34.5 18.730418
2:  1969 34.5 14.890535
3:  1970 34.5 14.475564
4:  1971 34.5  7.380579
5:  1972 34.5 12.090908
6:  1973 34.5 18.565517`

Comment: @AFH that's because the ```data.table``` call above doesn't modify the original ```dat```.  You would have to do a new assignment, i.e., ```mod_res <- dat[, .(pred = ...), by = years]```